# Docker-Compile how indicate the directory

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I need to create a container image for python. I have created a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. I build the image, but the wrong directory is set for the project. I see the following error:

```
web_1    | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Structure of the project:

```
folder_project
|
|-django.testsite: manage.py and other files
|-python: Docerfile
|-docer-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
 web:
  build: ./python
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
 redis:
  image: "redis:alpine"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN easy_install pip
RUN pip install django==1.9.12

ADD . /django.testsite
WORKDIR /django.testsite

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong context path. Use:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: python/Dockerfile
```

Comment: The Dockerfile will need to reflect this change as well for `ADD`